# A counting riddle - Who am I?

Tags: riddle

The colors of the rainbow were not enough, I needed 8.

You probably heard about me before you were 7.

To learn my name you had to count to 25.

But you needed already know me to learn to count to 24.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you a

> Xylophone

The colors of the rainbow were not enough, I needed 8.

> The xylophone needs at least 8 thingies, hence 8 colours for musical reasons. Also hidden in the text we can see "were **not e**nough", perhaps accidental, but perhaps hinting it is related to music. [image: Picture of a children's xylophone with coloured notes]

You probably heard about me before you were 7.

> The image above shows a xylophone one would encounter at a young age, not sure what else 7 could refer to.

To learn my name you had to count to 25.

> Here I guess that counting to 25, is as other suggested, actually reciting the alphabet up until the 25th letter, which is **Y**, and you need it to spell the word x**Y**lophone

But you needed already know me to learn to count to 24.

> When kids learn the alphabet, it is very common to learn by associating pictures with the letters. A common thing associated with the 24th letter, i.e. **X**, is of course, a Xylophone.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This is a great first answer, and I think it's correct!

Answer (score 11):

Maybe it's a too-far-away Association, but here is my answer:

> Crayola Crayons

The colors of the rainbow were not enough, I needed 8

> 8 Colors were in the original color box 1903.
>
>  Source: http://www.crayola.com/faq/your-history/what-were-the-original-eight-8-colors-in-the-1903-box-of-crayola-crayons/

You probably heard about me before you were 7

> Yes, when I was a child, I probably paint something with them

To learn my name you had to count to 25.

> Yes, because the name include an Y, the 25 letter in alphabet

But you needed already know me to learn to count to 24.

> The actual box has 24 colors [image: crayola colors]

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with letter "Y" pronounced as "Why"? Little children ask "Why" all the time; Y is the 25-th letter; the word twenty-four contains the letter "Y". (The color clue do not seem to fit.)

Comment: @Gamow: Maybe my imagination ran riot.

Answer (score 2):

A *bit* far-stretched but I think it is about

> Colors that a computer stores.

The colors of the rainbow were not enough, I needed 8.

> [8-bit color graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_color)

You probably heard about me before you were 7.

> In the link given above, you can see in the table that numbers 0 and 1 are assigned to Blue color. 2,3,4 to Green color. 5,6,7 to Red. Clearly, the numbers are assigned till 7.

To learn my name you had to count to 25.

> 'Count' here means 'to include'. So it is about that the maximum number of colors that can be displayed at any one time, that is 256. And you can clearly see 25 here.

But you needed already know me to learn to count to 24.

> 24-bit color (also called 'true color') has 16,777,216 color variations and the human eye can discriminate up to ten million colors. So, we get all colors we can discriminate in it.

Answer (score 2):

It's the

> alphabet

---

The colors of the rainbow were not enough, I needed 8.

> the word "alphabet" is 8 letters long.

You probably heard about me before you were 7.

> most children learn the alphabet before age 7

To learn my name you had to count to 25. 
But you needed already know me to learn to count to 24.

> there are 26 letters in the alphabet. Also, children are often encouraged to wash their hands for 24-25 seconds, but since many learn their ABCs before learning to count as higher than 10, many children simply wash their hands while saying/singing the alphabet.